# How can I do some calculation between dates values in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given that I have article.created_at value, I'd like to allow user to edit the article only if created_at is less than 7 days ago. If it was created_at more than 7 days ago, I do not want to let user to edit the article.

I tried using

```
DateTime.now.to_i - article.created_at.to_i
```

but it only shows time difference between them in seconds. Of course, I can use seconds to calculate 7 days, but I'd like to know if there is a better way doing this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a method in your Article model to test from the controller that does something like this:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  def editable?
    self.created_at > 7.days.ago
  end

end
```

Then back in the controller or a view:

```
if @some_article.editable?
  # Show edit link
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
article.created_at > 1.week.ago
```